# jQuery serializeArray not picking up dynamically created form elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, serializearray

I've got a form that's dynamically created using ajax (as data for the form elements has to come from a database) and I want to serialize the elements of the form to submit by ajax. I'm currently just testing my theory using code from the jQuery website just to see if I can pick up the form elements and this is where the problem lies:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnCustomSearch').live('click', function() {
            $('#results').html('');
            alert($('#customSearchTable :input').serializeArray());
            // get all the inputs into an array.
            var fields = $('#customSearchTable :input').serializeArray();
            jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field) {
                $("#results").append(field.name + " = " + field.value + ", ");
            });

            // now we'll reformat the data as we need

            // here we'll send the data via ajax

    });
});
```

I need to make some changes to the data prior to submission and this code is not written yet, but what I'm finding is that any input elements on the page that existed at time of page loading are picked up correct, any elements that are populated using Javascript are picked up correctly, but any created using ajax are ignored.

I know this is normally resolved using "live", but I'm unclear as to how to resolve this with `serializeArray()`. Using Ajax additional form elements are added to the `#customSearchTable` and these are the ones not being picked up.

Any help great appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This method doesn't care when the elements were added, it seems that they aren't being added correctly as form elements, can you post that code?  For example, do they have a `name` attribute on them?

Comment: Nick, thanks so much, you're right, the dynamically generated form elements were missing the name attribute.... DOH!!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: FML - 1 hour later :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll expound upon the comment a bit more here:

When you call [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) it's looping through just as a `<form>` submission would or as close as possible anyway, to get the elements to be submitted.  The key part [is here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L91):

```
.filter(function() {
  return this.name && !this.disabled &&
         (this.checked || rselectTextarea.test(this.nodeName) ||
         rinput.test(this.type));
})
```

Just as a `<form>` submit wouldn't include elements without a [`name` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.name), the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) call using `this.name` will filter those elements out of ones to be serialized.

Comment: Thanks Nick, hope that clarifies it for anyone else having the same issue.

Comment: got a fix for `<option />` elements added to an already named `<select />`?

Comment: @Louis how do you mean?  I'm not sure I follow here...any `<option>` with a `value` attribute will serialize here, if it lacks the `value` attribute then it'll use the text as the value (that's standard browser behavior).  If you have an example or need more info I'm happy to answer...just describe a bit more what you're after.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm creating the empty `<select />`s in a template, and adding the options dynamically with `$('<option></option>').val(stringkey).html(stringkey).appendTo('#stringkeys');`, when I call `.serialize()` on the form the selected options aren't being returned if that makes sense?

Comment: @Louis `.val()` isn't valid on an `<option>` element (it's not the same as setting a value attribute), only a `<select>`.  You want to set the `value` attribute on the option instead, like this: `$('<option/>', { value : stringkey }).text(stringkey).appendTo('#stringkeys');`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that finds this as an "issue", please note that as per Nick Craver's comment above, all that's required is to ensure that the "name" attribute is appended to the new form elements that are created dynamically. This resolved my problem! Thank you very much indeed Nick!